# Profile picture displays improperly on new dashboard

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, profile-picture

[image: The profile picture is lower than it should be and overlaps some buttons]

I looked at other sites but I don't have the new profile on any of those

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yeah, so... That page isn't even close to being done. There's a setting to control visibility, and... somehow it got set to the wrong thing.

On *the one site that gets the most traffic*.

For a brief moment, we thought maybe no one noticed. Sorry for doubting you!

It's off now, and will stay off until it's actually somewhere near done - and then it'll be enabled for testing on Meta first.

Comment: Dammit. I missed it. :(

Comment: so it'll be enabled for testing on meta first AFTER it is brought to the community for discussion?

Comment: After / when / during... I don't know what the timeframe is gonna be like for this, given it's been under development for many, many months thus far @lostsock - [here's the most recent discussion though](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231112/profile-page-makeover-part-2-the-prototype), if you're interested in chiming in.

Comment: I'm fairly aware of that post since I received a great answer badge for my answer there. I was under the assumption that the general consensus was that it wasn't worth redoing the redesign like this, since the about me section is hideous, and that our goal shouldn't be more user centered *(facebookish)* instead of content centered. Sure if they want a apps/projects section, just add another tab to the current layout. However, if they've been working non stop for the last 3 months on this, then I'd like to see how improved it is and possibly re-evaluate my popular opinion.

Comment: As you might be able to tell from the screenshot, the old design has been scrapped/reworked a few times since then @lostsock - it's still not exactly *finished*, although I'd have to say it's inching closer to being usable. Once there's something reasonable stable again, I'm sure there'll be a repeat of the past discussion.